# xdebug trace and profiler files using trigger value

Tags: php, xdebug, profiler, trace

About `xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value` : "This setting can be used to restrict who can make use of the XDEBUG_TRACE functionality as outlined in xdebug.trace_enable_trigger. When changed from its default value of an empty string, the value of the cookie, GET or POST argument needs to match the shared secret set with this setting in order for the trace file to be generated." (xdebug doc).  Equivalent for `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value`

I have xdebug 2.2.3, and this in php.ini :

```
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value="miko"
```

But if I pass anything as value for XDEBUG_TRACE parameter (whether by a get parameter or a cookie), it will still generates trace files. So how can I make this trigger value really work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade your xdebug to higher than v2.3 for this to work, from the documentation:

```
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value
Type: string, Default value: "", Introduced in Xdebug >= 2.3
This setting can be used to restrict who can make use of the XDEBUG_TRACE functionality as outlined in xdebug.trace_enable_trigger. When changed from its default value of an empty string, the value of the cookie, GET or POST argument needs to match the shared secret set with this setting in order for the trace file to be generated.
```